# What is the correct argument type for std::less<int>?

Tags: c++, templates

I am making a class -- a BST -- that can compare templated nodes, which require a comparator, such as `std::less`.

the tree is like so :

```
template<typename T, typename comparator>
class tree
{
private:
    comparator compare;
public:
    explicit tree (comparator functor);
};
```

But I can't seem to find which template type I should input in my application.

```
tree<int> my_bst (std::less<int>);

error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
 bst::tree<int> my_bst (std::less<int>);
```

And it makes sense because my template type is incomplete.

How should I profile my constructor?

What is named that property of the templates? Because all I find about that is the `sort` page on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Typically, I can use `sort` like so

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::sort(v.begin (), v.end (), std::less<>());
```

How come the specialization of less is deduced? How can I replicate that?

Comment: Don't confuse *template* arguments with *constructor* arguments.  Try `tree<int, std::less<int>> my_bst(std::less<int>);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To save yourself, and everyone else that just wants a default behavior, the extra keystrokes in telling the compiler the type of the comparator you could instead set it by default and then you only have to specify it if you want a different behavior.

```
template<typename T, typename comparator = std::less<T>>
class tree
{
private:
    comparator compare;
public:
    explicit tree (comparator functor = comparator{});
};
```

Will default `comparator` to the type `std::less<T>` and lets you construct the class like

```
tree<int> my_bst;
```

Then, if you want to use a different type, like `std::greater`, then you would use

```
tree<int, std::greater<int>> my_bst;
```

---

As you have it right now you would have to use

```
tree<int, std::less<int>> my_bst(std::less<int>{});
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          |                      pass an instance of the comparator to the constructor
          |
          tell the compiler the type of the comparator
```

to make a `tree` using `std::less<int>`.

---

As for why you can do

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::sort(v.begin (), v.end (), std::less<>());
```

`std::less` has been specialized for [`std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) in C++14 and it provides an `operator ()` that is templated and will deduce the types passed to it.  That means an object of `std::less<>` can compare any two types so long as the expression

```
decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs))
```

is valid where both `T` and `U` are parameter types to the `operator ()`.